# Update two updatepanels simultaneously together

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have two ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanels .
there are two timers with diffrent intervals.
is it possible to update two updatepanels simultaneously  together ?
like multi thread application .
each should be UpdatePanel Update in separate thread in one time.
i wrote this code but second timer does not work :

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000">
    </asp:Timer>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="2000">
    </asp:Timer>
</asp:Content>
```

Behind Code :

```
  Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            Label1.Text = Date.Now
        End Sub

        Protected Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
            Label2.Text = Date.Now
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your UpdatePanels are useless in this example, because your Timers are *outside* of them. As a result, every time your event gets triggered, it does a full page refresh. (This is in part why you never see the second Timer get hit -- by the time the first timer gets hit, the entire page gets refreshed, so the counter resets on the first timer)

So, you need to accomplish two things to fix your page:

1. Get the UpdatePanels to work properly with the Timers so that only **asynchronous** postbacks are occurring.
2. Make sure that each Timer only causes one UpdatePanel to refresh.

The first can be taken care of by either moving the Timer into the UpdatePanel, as a child, or by using the `<asp:Triggers>` element to basically say *"The only thing that will update my UpdatePanel is this timer."*

The second can be taken care of by setting the `UpdateMode=Conditional` attribute on each UpdatePanel.

Try this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="Timer2_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
</asp:Content>
```

I have to run to work now, so bear with me if you have any questions ;-)

Comment: tnQ very much :) but  Second UpdatePanel will update after first updatepanel.
is there any way to update them together ?

Comment: Well, I'm not _certain_ about this, but I think the problem is that each Timer has its own javascript timer, and the page's javascript is running single-threaded, so there's absolutely no way that you're going to have both timers firing at the same time.

Can't you just use one Timer?

Comment: no because Timers has not same interval . its just an example.
i think its better to use a webmethod and javascript Timer. then i will update both updatepanels in separate threads. good ?